# how to visualize quadrangle in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a proper way to visualize quadrangles in rviz. The quadrangles are from a dynamically updated map representing a terrain environment.

The closest display type I can find in rviz is the 2d map, but it is limited to 2d flat ground while in my case the elevation of cells has to be considered; another close approach is to visualize the vertexes of quadrangle, but no color filling of the quadrangles can be achieved.

thanks for any advices
clark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29604/how-to-visualize-quadrangle-in-rviz/) by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 393 on 2012-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way is probably to manually generate triangles for a visualization_msgs/Marker.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on 2012-03-13**:
Agree, I think this a way worth trying. Thanks.